# Dogbreed classification/CNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, imagenet

I am struggling with training a CNN model to identify dogbreeds. I intend to train the Stanford Dogs Dataset using ResNet architecture. I downloaded the dataset from http://vision.stanford.edu/aditya86/ImageNetDogs/ into google-colab notebook and have extracted the images in the dataset. I get a folder structure like this: [folder_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7vjh.png). I know I need the folder structure which has subfolders train and test and then further subfolders with images of dogs with corresponding species. How do I go along doing that?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the folders?

Comment: Yes. I want to create a folder structure where the images dataset in first subdivided into test and train folders and these (train and test) have further subfolders for each breed with images of dogs from that corresponding breed.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: OS : Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to strictly create separate folders for train and test. You can use the method [`tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) from tensorflow. It lets you load your all-in-one-folder dataset taking the right split while loading. This is how:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/images/",  # path to your data folder
    validation_split=0.2,  # percentage reserved for test
    subset="training",  # this dataset is for training
    seed=1024  # must be the same for both train and test: ensures that you take the images consistently 
)
test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "/images/",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1024
)
```

Both functions return a `tf.data.Dataset` object. The argument `validation_split` lets you specify the percentage of data to reserve for validation (test in your case). In the example above I chose 80% train and 20% validation.

The `seed` argument must be the same for both `train_ds` and `test_ds`, because it ensures that the images are taken in same order, so you don't end up with mixed images in your train and test split.

Comment: Thank you :). This was very helpful. Could you also suggest me from where can I read/learn/practice the data loading, structurizing and the preprocessing part to improve myself in this further?

Comment: No problem; sure, have a look at this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images?hl=en